# VirtualBox resize disk not taking effect

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, partitioning, virtual-machine

I am trying to increase the size of my `/dev/sda1` (boot) following [this tutorial](http://nowfromhome.com/resize-virtualbox-linux-guest-drive)

I am able to execute the following command successfully:

```
VBoxManage.exe modifyhd ubuntu.vdi –-resize 40000
```

and when I go to “*My Vm*” -> “*Settings*” -> “*Storage*” -> “*my.vdi*” I see the correct (increased storage). When I run `GParted` via Live CD I do not see the new size. So the change took effect in the VirtualBox console, but not in the guest OS. What am I doing wrong?

Host: Windows 8
Guest: Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set up the drive up to be static one or a drive which increases as it needs?

Maybe it has problems upping the space if its the auto increase one, not sure though.

Comment: It does allocate space dynamically (auto increase). But why would that be an issue?

Answer (score 2):

For future references, after the 'modifyhd --resize' to grow (cannot shrink) the dynamic disk; you must unmount the VDI and remount it (easiest way is to use the UI to unattach the VDI, and reattach it).  Once that's done, then do the usual ritual of gparted.

Comment: This helped me, since it helped me discover the issue was with the underlying snapshot vdi. After I (also) resized that one, the new size showed up in the VM.

Comment: I am having the same issue.  How to unattach and reattach the VDI?

Comment: me too, the problem still the same. It shows virtual size 84, actual size 54, but comming into GParted, there's no unallocated space to increase my disk space from.